# Spaces always switches to first space when clicking on icon in Dock

Tags: macos, dock, spaces, ventura

I run MacOS Ventura 13.5.2. I use spaces and have quite a lot of applications open in fullscreen mode. So, one application takes up one space. When I now click on the application icon in the dock, MacOS usually switches to the first space where I have some finder windows open, **but not the application I clicked on**. This is super annoying, and I have had this issue for quite a while.

- It happens with many different applications. VS Code, Brave, Table
  Plus, iTerms, etc.
- I tried turning the setting "When switching to an
  application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application"
  in Desktop & Dock settings on and off. Doesn't do anything.
- When I click on the application a second time it gets me there.

These are my current settings. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I don't want to always zoom out and switching from Space 2 to 8 with CTRL + Arrow is quite annoying.

[image]

Comment: I have had this issue for years. I doubt that the update will fix it...